# Why does using the await operator for the second argument to a method affect the value of the first argument?

Tags: c#, parameters, arguments, async-await, parameter-passing

The following C# program produces unexpected output.  I would expect to see:

> Value1: 25, Value2: 10
>
> Value1: 10, Value2: 25

but instead I see

> Value1: 0, Value2: 10
>
> Value1: 10, Value2: 25

```
namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DoWork().Wait();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private async static Task DoWork()
        {
            SomeClass foo = new SomeClass()
            {
                MyValue = 25.0f
            };

            PrintTwoValues(foo.MyValue, await GetValue());
            PrintTwoValues(await GetValue(), foo.MyValue);
        }

        static void PrintTwoValues(float value1, float value2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Value1: {0}, Value2: {1}", value1, value2);
        }

        static Task<float> GetValue()
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    return 10.0f;
                });
        }

        class SomeClass
        {
            private float myValue;

            public float MyValue
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.myValue;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.myValue = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can somebody explain to me why it is that using the "await" operator in the expression for the second argument to the `PrintTwoValues` method seems to be affecting the value of the first argument?

My guess is that it must have something to do with the fact that the argument list is evaluated left-to-right.  In the first call to `PrintTwoValues` I'm guessing that the return value from `SomeClass.MyValue` gets pushed onto the stack.  Then execution continues into `GetValue` which just starts the Task and exits.  Then `DoWork` exits and schedules a continuation that will call `PrintTwoValues` but when that continuation runs the value that had originally gotten pushed on the stack is somehow lost and reverted back to its default value.

While there are simple ways to workaround this problem, like storing the arguments in temporary variables before passing them to the `PrintTwoValues` method, I'm mostly just curious why this behavior is occurring.

Note:  I'm using Visual Studio 2013, Update 5.  I'm building a console application that is targeting .NET Framework 4.5 and running on Windows 10 Enterprise.

Comment: I get what you expect to get.

Comment: Does the behavior change in debug/release mode?

Comment: Interesting.  I had not tried it in Release mode.  It looks like I DO get the expected result in Release, but not in Debug.

Comment: Looks like another .NET bug?

Comment: @AndreyNasonov, that's what I'm inclined to think as well, but I tend to shy away from that explanation until I'm absolutely confident that it's not something that I'm doing incorrectly.

Comment: Unable to repro here, on VS2015.

Comment: Does replacing `Task.Factory.StartNew` with `Task.Run` make any difference? - http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html

Comment: @StephenCleary Same here, but I can repro in VS2013 and LinqPad 4. Interestingly, LinqPad 5 doesn't have the issue. I thought it was down to .Net Framework version but dropping VS2015 to 4.5 doesn't make the issue appear. So perhaps it's related to the C# 5?

Comment: @PauloMorgado, using `Task.Run` does not make a difference.  However, thanks for the pointer to that article.  I was unaware of the dangers of `Task.Factory.StartNew`.

Comment: I'm getting the same, @DavidG. That makes it a compiler issue as the framework is the same.

Comment: OK, it's a compiler bug. Pointless to report it because VS13 is going away. VS15 works. (I can repro it in VS13 debug). Accept the answer and we are done here.

Comment: @usr Going away doesn't mean not supported though. I think it's still worth reporting. Not that they will necessarily fix it as it may break existing code.

Comment: @DavidG if you want it fixed go ahead. I do *not* want it fixed. I want the dev time spent elsewhere for example with new features. I'd prefer that they *not* fix the bug.

Comment: @usr It's unlikely that it's a simple equation like that. Mainstream support from Microsoft for VS2013 runs until 2019 which means they will be producing fixes for it for 4 years yet and many people will be using the product till then and beyond. I'd rather let MS decide what is appropriate to be fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've tested the code both with the C#5 compiler and the C#6 compiler using respectively [LinqPad 4](http://www.linqpad.net/) and [LinqPad 5](http://www.linqpad.net/) and I could reproduce the issue.

This looks like a compiler bug of the C#5 compiler, because when I decomplied both versions with [.NET Reflector 9](https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2015/08/05/beta-release-of-c6-support-in-net-reflector/), I got different code:

#### C#5:

```
private async static Task DoWork()
{
    float myValue;
    SomeClass foo = new SomeClass {
        MyValue = 25f
    };
    float introduced6 = await GetValue();
    PrintTwoValues(myValue, introduced6);
    float introduced7 = await GetValue();
    PrintTwoValues(introduced7, foo.MyValue);
}
```

#### C#6:

```
private async static Task DoWork()
{
    SomeClass foo = new SomeClass {
        MyValue = 25f
    };
    float myValue = foo.MyValue;
    float num2 = await GetValue();
    float asyncVariable1 = num2;
    PrintTwoValues(myValue, asyncVariable1);
    num2 = await GetValue();
    float asyncVariable2 = num2;
    PrintTwoValues(asyncVariable2, foo.MyValue);
}
```

Notice that, for C#5, the `myValue` variable is declared before the declaration of of `foo` and never initialized before the first call to `PrintTwoValues`.

Comment: hmmm can it be that it is a problem of the code optimization that the compilers do? (depending on compile settings they can do some optimizations....or at least try to do them)